# Custom Click tracking for Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-analytics, vuejs2, analytics

Here is a problem I am facing. I want to build a podcast recommendation engine and wanted some behavior click information. Here is the app https://podflix.app

- What is the source page or the podcast ID
- And which podcast or recommendation people clicked for a given source podcast.
- Also what tracking library to use for custom json tracking? I am currently using google analytics but can't send custom json in events data.

Is there a way to get this information tracked automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com) for this. Look into [auto event variables](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/auto-event-variable-google-tag-manager/) in GTM.

Then look at [click triggers](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679320?hl=en) and [event tracking](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716?hl=en) in GTM. Tie these together you should be able to form a solution. Give it a try and let me know if you run into issues.

Example,
For podcast id you would create a link click trigger and register the GA event to track the "href" of the link in the event label.